# Arabic stemmer doesn't work for sentences

Tags: python, arabic, stemming

I have python 2.7 and  i installed [this](http://www.arabicstemmer.com/) , I have this code :

```
from snowballstemmer import stemmer
ar_stemmer = stemmer("arabic")
stem = ar_stemmer.stemWord(u"مكتبة لمعالجةالكلمات العربية وتجذيعها  ")
print stem
```

When i run it, i get the same sentence without stem  مكتبة  لمعالجة  الكلمات  العربية  وتجذيعها , so what should i change ?

Answer (score 2):

Split the sentence on words like this:

```
from snowballstemmer import stemmer
ar_stemmer = stemmer("arabic")
sentence = u"مكتبة لمعالجة الكلمات العربية وتجذيعها"
for word in sentence.split(" "):
    stem = ar_stemmer.stemWord(word)
    print stem
```